# Can "how to do X?" be a duplicate of "I have X,how do I do Y"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I found a question which asks for generic function of C++ template:

[Java generics vs C++ templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285384/java-generics-vs-c-templates)

And I found another question which has generic function of C++ as demo, but asks for the Java version:

[In Java, is writing a single function or class to handle arbitrary multidimensional ArrayList possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151827/in-java-is-writing-a-single-function-or-class-to-handle-arbitrary-multidimensio)

On one hand, the latter question seems contained what the OP need(I think), on the other hand, the latter one is asking about different things, and the "answer" is appearing at the question body instead of at answer fields.

Are they actually duplicates? Is it appropriate or misleading to mark the former one as duplicate of the latter one?

Comment: I don't see a dupe here.  I see two questions comparing C++ templates to Java generics with slightly different motives.

Comment: I don't think we use content in the *question* of one post as the answer for another in order to mark it as a duplicate. That would get confusing: people look for answers in the answer section of a post. It would probably be helpful for that OP to link to that question with a note telling them that the code in the question itself would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it will be useful information in the majority of cases, you cannot (always) label an existing X-to-Y solution as an answer to a Y-to-X question.

As a *possible* answer? Sure. But you're talking about making it a duplicate; which entails closing the second question, which inherently means that no other equally meaningful answer can be given.

You should only close questions as duplicates if the already existing answer is definitively the best answer to this question. in other words, there is no point to rephrasing the same answer again and again.
But that is not yet proven for an Y-to-X question and a (supposedly duplicate) existing X-to-Y solution.

---

**A simple counter example**

> **Q** What is the square of 3?
>   **A** The square of 3 is 9.
>
> **Q** What is the square root of 9?

Should we mark this second question as a duplicate? From your post, I assume that you think it is a duplicate question.

However, while the topics are certainly overlapping, the correct answer to the second question is that the square root of 9 could be 3 **or -3**.

If you close this second question as a duplicate of the first, then you never included the possibility of a negative square root. That negative square root was never addressed in the first QA, since it was never part of the question.

---

Just because the X-to-Y has a strictly defined (and well accepted) answer, does not mean that you can automatically assume that the Y-to-X answer is the logical inversion, or that the answer is the same in any way.
While it (probably) is **an** answer to the question, it is not automatically **the best** answer to the question.

**However**, the example I gave only applies in a subset of cases. There will be numerous cases where you can actually correctly invert one solution to fit the other; and there won't be any issue whatsoever.

Because of this, I would not be in favor of *closing the question as a duplicate*; because closing a question means that no other meaningful answers can be given. And in these cases, it is possible that more meaningful answers exist.

I would suggest that you refer to the (supposedly duplicate) existing answer *inside* your posted answer to this new question.
You still get to refer to existing knowledge, which may or may not be the best possible answer. But you at least prevent the wrongful closure of a question that could have a better answer than the duplicate one.

---

You also don't run the risk of repetition. Once the Y-to-X question has been answered too; you can close any future X-to-Y **or** Y-to-X question as a duplicate of either the original X-to-Y question **or** the original Y-to-X question.

So I don't think this is an ongoing problem, it can only occur once for a given topic.

Comment: TL;dr: we mark questions as duplicated of other questions, not questions as duplicated of other answers.

Comment: @Braiam: That is not an accurate summary of my answer. Also, I'm not quite sure if you're right. Semantically speaking, you are right. But in practice, the most common duplicate I see on SO (nullreferences) are connected because the existing **answer** is a perfect answer to the new **question**. Even in cases where the question is different (e.g. about a specific error in a specific framework), but the solution boils down to preventing a nullreference. So therefore, it is a match based on the existing answer and the new question, not specifically the existing question itself.

Comment: Which is why the deduplication project started.

Comment: @Braiam: I'll take your word for it (no clue what it is); but I still disagree that duplicates are connected question-to-question.

Comment: "The thing that Stack Exchange was most interested in was how to recognise when two posts are falsely labeled as duplicates." [Can we see the results of Project Reduplication of Deduplication?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/296357)

Comment: We close questions as duplicates when the problem being solved is the same. The way we determine if the problems are the same, is by determining whether or not all solutions to both problems are equally solutions to the other problem.

Comment: @TinyGiant: But do we not factor in whether it is the _best possible_ answer when we label something as a duplicate? Just because the answer applies does not mean it is the best answer. Example: (old) question about string concatenation vs (new) question about string concatenation _for SQL queries_. The old answer applies to the new question (= it works and solves the presented problem), yet it is not the most appropriate answer (as it foregoes preventing SQL injection)

Comment: @TinyGiant: This may be a sematic niggle, but to be sure: "whether or not all solutions to both problems are equally solutions to the other problem" More often than not, a new question will be closed as a duplicate specifically because it has already been solved in the past. So you can't really compare if a (new) solution solves the (old/new) problem, since the closure of the (new) question prevents the posting of any (new) answers.

Comment: @Flater for any common duplicate it is fairly easy to determine the most common solutions to that problem. If there exists a that contains those solutions, they are duplicates.

Comment: Also not that by solution I do not mean example. The example implementations of the solution may differ, but the solution itself will be the same.